# How to see which Button is clicked in ArrayList

Tags: android, button, arraylist, onclick, onclicklistener

I have created an ArrayList with Buttons and I set the OnClickListener on all of them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        myButtons.add(new Button(this));
        myButtons.get(i).setOnClickListener(this);
        myButtons.get(i).setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

But how can I see now, in the onClick method, which Button is clicked?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Maybe I should say that i am really new in programming.

Comment: No it extends Activity does it has to extend Button?

Comment: you can add id to button like myButtons.setID(i); and in onclick v.getid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you add the Button to the list, set a tag like this:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
button.setTag(i);
```

And then the index can be retrieved with:

```
int index = (Integer) button.getTag();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a tag to all the buttons that you add, and in onClick you can do something as v.getTag() to check which button was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can store any additional information using methods `setTag()/getTag()`

```
myButtons.get(i).setTag(id);

listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doAction(v.getTag());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Set for each button id, for example:

```
...
Button button= new Button(this);
temp.sedId(i);
temp.setOnClickListener(this);
myButtons.add(button);
...
```

And then in `onClick` react on clicked button for example:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    ...
    case 17:
        //Some action
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement interface `OnClickListener` in your activity.Use `button.setId(id)` to set Id for each button.Try following code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            break;

        case R.id.button2:


            break;

        case R.id.button3:

            break;


        default:
            break;
    }

}
```